# I have been trying to install the Arcade library for python but I keep getting the same error and have no idea how to fix it

Tags: python, arcade

my python is ver 3.11 and I want to install the arcade library because I use it in school and want to make my own stuff at home but every time I try the 'pip3 install arcade' command in the command prompt I get an error message:

```
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
     [end of output]

 note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
 ERROR: Failed building wheel for pymunk
Failed to build pymunk
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pymunk, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I tried running the command prompt as administrator and using a powershell 7 version (i dont even know what that is) and some other random things I tried and cant remember but the error message never changes
I have tried installing the vscode version from the link but its not much use unless I've done something wrong (possible).
no idea at all as to what this means and Ive tried all kinds of fixes and nothing seems to work :(
I'm just pretty lost on this and any help would be appreciated

Comment: vscode is not the same thing as MS Visual C++

Comment: What is the OS?

Comment: Same question. Windows 10.

Comment: Should be fixed in 2.6.13, but you should really have used the 2.7 pre-release. The problem was missing binary distribution for pymunk so it tries to compile it during install. If you have MS build tools installed it works fine. You don't need that any more. Also you can also just ask in arcade discord or github.